# Writing pandas df to csv with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement

I have a 3-column dataframe and I want to write certain rows that meet *if* condition into a new csv.

Original dataframe:[image]

Chunk of the code which is supposed to do what I need:

```
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_out, orient='index')

res.columns = ['id', 'id2', 'Similarity']

for index, row in res.iterrows():
    if row[2] > 0.8:
        row.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

The output I want:[image]

The output I actually get:[image]

What am doing wrong in writing to csv? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just slice the dataframe beforehand and then write it. As in:

```
df_to_write = res[res['Similarity']>0.8]

df_to_write.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_out, orient="columns")
res.columns = ['id', 'id2', 'Similarity']

final_row = []
for index, row in res.iterrows():
    if row['Similarity'] > 0.8:
        final_row.append(index)

res.iloc[final_row].to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```